# SQL Server : insert into select where sortorder is equal to inserted primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a query like so:

```
INSERT INTO TableA (value1, value2) 
  SELECT Value1, Value2 
  FROM TableB 
  WHERE TableB.sortOrder = THE ID FOR THE RECORD GETTING INSERTED
```

What I am trying to do is insert into `TableA` with values from `TableB` where the `TableB.sortOrder` is equal to the id for the record getting inserted. Is what I am trying to do even possible? Or do I have to put `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` into a variable and do a separate select and then an update?

Comment: Could you give example input and your desired output.

Comment: Your expected result appears not to agree with the description.

Comment: According to your provided description, It should insert all the four rows of TableB. As in all 4 cases, the _ID_ = _SortOrder_. I think, you are missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Increment the max id from TableA in a sub query, ensure you are populating id explicitly in the scenario where multiple inserts are contending for the same inserts:

```
INSERT INTO TableA (id, value1, value2) 
SELECT sortOrder, Value1, Value2 FROM TableB 
WHERE TableB.sortOrder = (select max(id) + 1 from TableA)
```

Not sure this is a good design decision, there could be potential primary key violations when many inserts are contending.